# JavaScript HTML Navigation with my html and JS code

Tags: javascript, html

I got a problem with my code, for school, i need to do 3 different methods to navigate to image to image.
First Method : http://www.w3im.com/fr/js/js_htmldom_navigation.html
Second Method : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
Third Method : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
I try but i don't know where is the problem
It's the first exercice of this : http://bjobard.perso.univ-pau.fr/Cours/CIW/TP5.html
can anyone help me ?

```js
function changeImageM1(url, nom) {
  console.log("DEBUG : changeImageM1 : url = "+url+", nom = "+nom);
  console.log(document.body.childNodes[3]);
  document.body.childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].innerHTML = nom;
  document.body.childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].firstChild.src = url;

 
}

function changeImageM2(id_url, id_nom, url, nom) {
  console.log("DEBUG : changeImageM2 : id_url = " + id_url + ", id_nom = " + id_nom
              +", url = " + url + ", nom = " + nom);
 document.getElementById(id_nom).innerHTML = nom;
 document.getElementById(id_url).src = url; 
}

function changeImageM3(url, nom) {
  console.log("DEBUG : changeImageM3 : url = "+url+", nom = "+nom);

  document.querySelector("#id_quoi").innerHTML = nom;
  document.querySelector("#id_image").src = url; 
}

function changeImage(id_url, id_nom, url, nom) {
  document.getElementById("id_quoi").innerHTML = "Images/yearbyyear-ppg.png";
  document.getElementById("id_image").src = "Images/all-time-scoring.png"; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr">
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Une page web en HTML5</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Pages_libres/galerie.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/style.css" /> 
  </head>
<header>
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
          <img src="Images/image_accueil.png" alt="Galerie" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="4">
          <h1>Galerie</h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="../accueil.xhtml">Accueil</a></td>
      <td><a href="../Page_imposée/Livre_Choisi/livre.xhtml">Kobe -The Story of the NBA's Rising
        Young Star Kobe Bryant</a></td>
      <td><a href="1_presentation.xhtml">Présentation</a></td>
      <td><a class="actif" href="2_galerie.xhtml">Galerie</a></td>
    <td><a href="3_connexion.xhtml">Connexion</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </header>
<body>
  <h1>Kobe Story in 8 Pictures</h1>
    <p><b id="id_quoi">Le début...</b></p>
    <p><img id="id_image" src="Images/image-1-galerie" height="350px"/></p>
    <label>Méthode 1 : </label>
 <img id="id_trophy" src="Images/trophy.png" height="350px"/>
  <input type="button" value="All Time lakers" onclick="changeImageM1('Images/lakers-all-time.png', 'All Time Lakers')"
    />
    <br/>
   <label>Méthode 2 : </label>
    <input type="button" value="scoring-games" onclick="changeImageM2('Images/scoring-games.png', 'id_quoi', 'Images/yearbyyear-ppg.png', 'Score')"
    />
 <input type="button" value="Highest PPG" onclick="changeImageM2('Images/highest-ppg.png', 'Highest PPG')"
    />
 <br/>
 <label>Méthode 3 : </label>
    <input type="button" value="PPG" onclick="changeImageM3('Images/yearbyyear-ppg.png', 'PPG')"
    />
 <input type="button" value="All Time Scoring" onclick="changeImageM3('Images/all-time-scoring.png', 'All Time Scoring')"
    />
 </body>

  <script>
  var bodyTag = document.body;
  var label1   = bodyTag.childNodes[3];
  var bTag    = p1Tag.lastChild;
  var p2Tag   = bodyTag.childNodes[5];
  var imgTag  = p2Tag.firstChild;

  console.log("p1Tag  : "+ p1Tag.innerHTML);
  console.log("bTag   : "+ bTag.innerHTML);
  console.log("imgTag : "+ imgTag.src);
  </script>
 <body style="height:100%;" oncontextmenu="changeCouleurDeFond()">
   <h1> CLIC DROIT POUR CHANGER DE COULEUR </h1>
   <script>
   function changeCouleurDeFond() {
     var rgb = [Math.floor(Math.random()* 255), Math.floor(Math.random()* 255), Math.floor(Math.random()* 255)];
     var rgbfinal =[rgb[0],rgb[1], rgb[2]];
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+ rgbfinal.join(",")+ ")";
     document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false");
   }
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: you don't have a variable p1Tag defined, just p2Tag.

Method 2: for some reason, the id you are passing can't be found by document.getElementById. I don't know if it's the reason, but it's better use a span instead of a b tag.

Method 3: The same, p1Tag is not defined.